# Mysql DISTINCT not working if I add another column

Tags: mysql, distinct

mysql> select DISTINCT title, id from myadmins;

```
+------+------------+
| id   | title      |
+------+------------+
|    1 | admin      |
|    2 | stack      |
|    3 | jeff       |
|    4 | admin      |
|    5 | stack      |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT**

What I want is not repeting the title column

```
+------+------------+
| id   | title      |
+------+------------+
|    2 | stack      |
|    3 | jeff       |
|    4 | admin      |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It's working fine. That's what `DISTINCT` is supposed to do. It means `DISTINCT **ROWS**`

Comment: What results did you want? Should it show `1` or `4` or both for the `admin` row? And similarly for `stack`

Comment: Looks DISTINCT to me; what result did you expect?

Comment: I don't need to repetitions

Comment: the result that I need is : admin, stack, jeff

Comment: @JeffBic - So don't select the `id` column then.

Comment: why did you choose to keep 4 for admin and not 1, and 2 in stack and not 5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DISTINCT` applies to the entire row of data. Since the `ID` is different on each row, then you will end up with duplicate titles.

If you need the `ID`, then you could use an aggregate to get the `MAX(ID)`:

```
select max(id) id,
  title
from yourtable
group by title
order by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dab7b/2)

Answer (score 2):

You will get distinct (id, title) couples.

The row with `id=1 and title=admin` is different from the row `id=4 and title=admin`.

If you want only distinct titles from your table:

```
select DISTINCT title from myadmins;

+------------+
| title      |
+------------+
| admin      |
| stack      |
| jeff       |
+------------+
```

Comment: no no, I don't get repeted rows, the result that I need is : admin, stack, jeff

Comment: @JeffBic - Which Id do you need then? You say you only want one row per `title` so what should that contain in the `id` column for `admin`?

Comment: I need to get title and id without repet the title

Comment: @JeffBic - Please stop just repeating the same thing and reply to the question above. You need to explain what your actual desired results would look like.

Comment: @JeffBic yes please edit your question and write what result you are expecting... You can't have a table with three title values and 5 id values

Comment: @JeffBic - So what rule are you using to select the `id` to show? If you always want the highest or always the lowest this is easy but the desired results seem arbitrary. Why not `5` for `Stack`? As it is `4` for `admin`?

Comment: How about to get by rand ordering ??

Comment: @JeffBic - So essentially you don't care? Any `id` will do?