# mysql get data from table without duplicates

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql DISTINCT not working if I add another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430121/mysql-distinct-not-working-if-i-add-another-column)

```
mysql> select DISTINCT number, id from table order by rand()

+------+------------+
| id   | number     |
+------+------------+
|    2 | 4          |
|    1 | 3          |
|    4 | 3          |
|    3 | 4          |
+------+------------+
```

I need to get something like that

```
+------+------------+
| id   | number     |
+------+------------+
|    2 | 4          |
|    4 | 3          |
+------+------------+
```

Refresh

```
+------+------------+
| id   | number     |
+------+------------+
|    3 | 4          |
|    1 | 3          |
+------+------------+
```

Refresh....

Comment: Did you really ask the same question twice withi 45 minutes (except you were satisfied with a non-random behavior)?

Comment: Are you saying each call to refresh chooses the duplicated ids that weren't chosen last time it was called? Or one call gets the duplicate with the latest ID, and the other with the minimum. What if its duplicated three times?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I guess a random ID is desired

Comment: My question is simple, I don't want to repeting the results and get random data

Comment: Ah just seen that at the top. Poor example data lead me astray.

Comment: @JeffBic. No it's not simple. Non-repetive means it's not random.

Comment: sorry, I will trying to solve it :(:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ( SELECT tt.id 
      FROM tableX AS tt 
      WHERE tt.number = t.number
      ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT 1
    ) AS id,
    number
FROM 
    tableX AS t
GROUP BY
    number ;
```